# How to get 15 minutes intervals only?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get in the minutes dropdown only these values, 00 15 30 and 45, how can we fix that?
I need like the screenshot below.

[image]

With the code below it works but I can't hide the values between 00 and 15, 15 and 30, 30 and 45. Does someone know how to fix that?

Thank you in advance.

```js
// Add an event listener for when the input changes
timeInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  // Get the current value of the input
  var currentTime = timeInput.value;

  // Split the current time into hours and minutes
  var parts = currentTime.split(':');
  var hours = parseInt(parts[0]);

  // Set the minutes to the nearest 15-minute interval
  var minutes = 0;
  var currentMinutes = parseInt(parts[1]);
  if (currentMinutes >= 0 && currentMinutes < 8) {
    minutes = 0;
  } else if (currentMinutes >= 8 && currentMinutes < 23) {
    minutes = 15;
  } else if (currentMinutes >= 23 && currentMinutes < 38) {
    minutes = 30;
  } else if (currentMinutes >= 38 && currentMinutes < 53) {
    minutes = 45;
  } else {
    minutes = 0;
    hours += 1;
  }

  // Format the adjusted time
  var adjustedTime = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;

  // Set the adjusted time back to the input
  timeInput.value = adjustedTime;
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Week Ending View</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css'>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="form-label">Start Time</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input id="timeInput" type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Time To Enter" aria-label="time to enter" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" step="900">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: FYI, your original code snippet had content outside the head and body elements. That's invalid HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field,
input[type="time"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field {
  display: none;
}

input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
  /* Hide the spin buttons */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="time" name="myTime" step="3600">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still see the value between 00 and 15, 15 and 30, 30 and 45. How can you show only these values?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My question is how to get in the minutes dropdown, the values 00 15 30 45 only, because right now I have all the minutes values. How to show only these values?

Comment: Please see [answer], then revise to provide some explanation of your solution.